# Tab key Press not focusing to next input in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using angularjs version 1.4.7, sometimes tab key press event is not focusing to next input.can anyone help me this issue.
used browser : Chrome
lang: angularjs

Comment: Can you reproduce it on some fiddle or I can see it working somewhere ?

Comment: that's the main problem i'm not able to reproduce the issue :)  as tab press works some times. if refresh page then it starts working normally.

Comment: Can you post the part of html code not working properly. Because without code or anywhere to look at the issue can't suggest you anything.

Comment: @NanditaSharma thank you for help :)  issue was not in my coding, origin of this issue was sweetalert js

Answer (score 0):

Try using tabindex="1" in next element
you can play around with sequence of flow in which next element should be focused

Comment: i can't do this in whole application as app has huge codebase. this does'nt happen all the times.

Comment: Well then there is no way solving it but to either add tab index of add a dedicated javascript code for same `code`$("#DialFirst").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialSecond").focus();
    });

    $("#DialSecond").keypress(function () {
        $("#DialThird").focus();
    }); <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="DialFirst" name="DialFirst" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialSecond" name="DialSecond" type="text" value="" /> `code`